# Простая админ-панель

Tags: php

Всем здрасте!нужно  управления контента главной страницы - Изменение первого блока главной страницы (заголовок, текст) а также изменение title, description всей главной страницы(на PHP).как это реализовать? проюзал 2 дня! толку 0.
Вот код html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="test.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<script src="#"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
 <div id="content">
 <div id="volna">волна</div>
<form action="test.php" method="POST" name="form1":>
<p><label><br><input type="text" name="name" size="35" maxlength="20" placeholder="Введите Ваше имя..."></label></p>
<p><label><input type="text" name="phone" size="35" maxlength="20" placeholder="Введите номер Вашего телефона..."></label></p>
<p><select size="1" name="hero">
    <option disabled>Выберите страну</option>
    <option value="Турция">Турция</option>
    <option value="Испания">Испания</option>
    <option value="Мальдивы">Мальдивы</option>
    <option value="Авганистан">Авганистан</option>

   </select></p>
  <p><input id="resetField" type="reset" name="reset" value="очистить"></p>
<p id="sendEmail"><input id="butt"type="image" src="https://us.123rf.com/450wm/kebox/kebox1407/kebox140700079/30339878-puzzle-button-send.jpg?ver=6" width="100" name="imagebutton"></p>
</form>

</div>
<div class="footer">Copyright © <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sergey.karachik" target="_blank">xlabuchik</a> 2017. All rights reserved.</div> 
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

дальше PHP

```
<?php
/* Осуществляем проверку вводимых данных и их защиту от враждебных 
скриптов */
$ip = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
$name = $_POST["name"];
$phone = htmlspecialchars($_POST["phone"]);
$hero =$_POST["hero"];
/* Устанавливаем e-mail адресата */
$myemail = "xlabuchik@gmail.com";
/* Проверяем заполнены ли обязательные поля ввода, используя check_input 
функцию */
$name = check_input($_POST["name"], "Пожалуйста, введите Ваше имя!");
$phone = check_input($_POST["phone"], "Укажите, пожалуйста, номер Вашего телефона! (Нужен, для того чтобы мы могли связаться с Вами).");

/* Создаем новую переменную, присвоив ей значение */
$message_to_myemail = "Hello! <br>
хотят отдохнуть в: $hero <br>
захотел: $name <br>
сказал чтоб перезвонили ему: $phone <br>
IP-адрес:$ip <br>
End";
/* Отправляем сообщение, используя mail() функцию */
$from  =  "From: $yourname <$email> \r\n Reply-To: $email \r\n"
          ."Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"utf-8\"\r\n";
mail($myemail, $tema, $message_to_myemail, $from);

?>
<p>Ваше сообщение было успешно отправлено!</p>
<p>На <a href="index.html">Главную >>></a></p>
<?php
/* Если при заполнении формы были допущены ошибки сработает 
следующий код: */
function check_input($data, $problem = "")
{
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0)
{
show_error($problem);
}
return $data;
}
function show_error($myError)
{
?>
<html>
<body>
<p>Пожалуйста, исправьте следующую ошибку:</p>
<?php echo $myError; ?>
</body>
</html>
<?php
exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: Мне кажется Вы ставите слишком абстрактную задачу. Т.е. "Сделайте за меня, а не подскажите как сделать"

Comment: задача мне сказали оч простая нужно создать админ панель чтобы менять титл и тд а я вот лузер не могу даже не знаю как ето реализовать

Answer (score 2):

Если чесно, я не совсем понял связь между текстом запроса и прикрепленным кодом. Ну да ладно, отвечу на текст. Как вариант вы можете подключиться к Базе Данных. Создать там таблицу homePageConfig и там прописать поля: id (PRIMARY A_I), configName (varchar 255), configValue (varchar 255).
Вставьте в эту таблицу запись:

```
 INSERT INTO homePageConfig (configName, configValue) VALUES ('webSiteTitle', "HELLO WORLD");
```

Потом создайте admin.php где будет форма с полем, например "Title".
Обработчик формы, подключится к БД, найдет содержимое поля webSiteTitle, и заменит его на значение из формы admin.php

Ну и для вывода результата. Ваш HTML файл должен превратиться в PHP. В нем вы подключитесь к БД, достанете нужную запись и выведете ее внутри тэга titile.
Например.

```
<?php

$title = PDO::query("SELECT configValue FROM homePageConfig WHERE configName = 'webSiteTitle'")->fetchColumn();

?>
<title><?=$title?></title>
```

Comment: Пишите все вопросы сюда. Другим тоже может быть интересно.

Comment: я в пшп банальный юзер а засорять сообщество тупыми вопросами стыдно))) если всетаки есть возможность по скайпу зарание благодарен!

Comment: Это сообщество и придумано для таких вопросов от банальных юзеров. Главное цель - научиться, а не ждать что сделают за вас.

Comment: Люди столкнуться с похожей проблемой и просто прочтут это все. И их проблема может решиться благодаря этому.

Comment: по админ панель я просмотрел кучу роликов на ютубе(там надо опен сервер а я хочу на хосте все ето реализовать) у меня 3 файла html css и php форма что мне еще нужно загузить на хост и как все это соеденить вместе

Comment: 1. Определитесь, что хотите получить в итоге. Если вы хотите управлять содержимым главной страницы веб-сайта с другой страницы, как я понимаю, то вам необходимо создать соответствующую страницу для управления, и связать управляемую страницу.

Comment: Как вы написали, и как я уже указывал, для корректной реализации с учетом последующей масштабируемости, вам понадобится База Данных (MySQL). Если на вашем хостинге или виртуальном веб-сервере есть таковая, то создайте файл admin.php. Загуглите: "как подключится к БД php". Там-же на php экранируйте форму с полем "Titile сайта"

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63855/discussion-between---and-xlabuchik).

Comment: Только данные нужно получать все скопом, например, в виде объекта или массива, а не по отдельности.

Comment: DaemonHK можете добавить в чат